# Name for the specific advertisement stands

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the name of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lraFY.jpg) type of advertising stands, or, to put it another way, how would you call them?

To clarify, there are two types of objects (shown in the link in ascending order):

1. Table promotional stands
2. Outside ground advertising stands

Of course, they could be called the way I referred to them, but maybe the community could propose a better term or the term that they have been using but is not an "officially approved" way of using the word.

Comment: I would call them "placards".  You can consult a thesaurus for other ideas.

Comment: I think the first type are called 'menu holders' as that's their usual function.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'menu holders' must be the type of sidewalk stands that have a menu on them, but I am talking about the promotional stand. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: [Must they?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=menu+holders&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI9NOXkuTVAhUMAcAKHV3tAscQ_AUICygC&biw=1659&bih=891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commercially they are called "A-Frame Signs," or "A-Frame Outdoor Signs," also often referred to as "Floor Stands," "Sidewalk Signs," and "Banner Stands."

Google these terms and see if they meet your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Kiosks have several uses, one of which is "a thick, columnlike structure on which notices, advertisements, etc., are posted." Dictionary.com

At a trade show, a booths would be "a stall, compartment, or light structure for the sale of goods or for display purposes, as at a market, exhibition, or fair." Dictionary.com